# HeapSort using build_min_heap and min_heapify "hand-made" functions

Tags: python, tree, heap, heapsort

I'm trying to implement the heap sort without using the 'heapq' library to try to understand the process behind each step involved in the heap sort process .I've tried and written the code Below but it doesn't give me any output.I don't seem to get what is the problem.Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here][1]

```
def min_heapify(array,element):
    left=(element*2)+1
    right=(element*2)+2
    length=len(array)-1
    smallest=element

    while left<=length and array[element]>array[left]:
        smallest=left
    while right<=length and array[smallest]>array[right]:
        smallest=right
    if smallest!=element:
        array[smallest],array[element]=array[element],array[smallest]
        min_heap(array,smallest)





def build_min_heap(array):
    n=len(array)-1
    array_sorted=[]
    for element in range(n//2,-1,-1):
        min_heapify(array,element)
    return array

def heapsort(array):
    aray=array.copy()
    sorted_array=[]
    build_min_heap(array)
    for i in range(len(array)):
        array[-1],array[0]=array[0],array[-1]
        sorted_array.append(array.pop())
        min_heapify(array,i)
    return sorted_array




array=[10,20,3,15,1000,60,16]
newarray=build_min_heap(array)
print(newarray)
```

Comment: In the `min_heapify` function you call min_heap, which isn't defined in your question code. Please add it

Comment: When you say that it doesn't give you any output, do you mean that it fails to run? Fails to terminate? Doesn't print the new array? As the previous comment pointed out, if the code you posted is what you're trying to run, it's going to fail because you didn't define `min_heap`. Did you perhaps mean `min_heapify` there? Also, when you call `min_heapify` in your `heapsort` function, the second parameter should be `0`, rather than `i`.

Comment: yeah,that was a typo which i corrected but it didn't work neither.I tried again with this code  but it always give me an error when comparing the right child to the parent,saying it's out of range.

Comment: def min_heapify(array,parent,size):
    left=(2*parent)+1
    right=(2*parent)+2
    smallest=parent
    if (left<=size-1) and (array[left]< array[parent]):
        smallest=left
    if (right<=size-1) and (array[right]<array[parent]):
        smallest=right
    if smallest!=parent:
        array[parent],array[smallest]=array[smallest],array[parent]
        min_heapify(array,smallest,size)

Comment: this is another variation which i tried:    def min_heapify2(array,parent,size):
    parentvalue=array[parent]
    left=(2*parent)+1
    while(left<size):
        if (left+1<size and array[left+1]<array[left]):
            left+=1
        if array[left]>parentvalue:
            break
        array[parent]=array[left]
        left=(2*left)+1
    array[parent]=parentvalue

Comment: sorrry for the lack of indentation

Comment: > *always give me an error when comparing the right child to the parent,saying it's out of range." Please edit your question and add the *exact* error message.